# reconnect() Prolems on Gottox-socket.io-java-client

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I'm using Gottox-socket.io-java-client on github.

thats so cool library ever i used. so easy and so powerful.

I'm developing android app with socket.io-java-client And ..... I found some problem on that.

i'm using recent version of socket.io-java-client and 
socket.io server version is 0.9.16 with node0.11.9-pre

after calling mSocket.disconnect() , the mSocket.reconnect() method not working.

so i tried connect() to reconnect instead of reconnect() 
but soon i faced with exception "You can connect your SocketIO instance only once. use a fresh instance instead"

Yes, I know that method ...
that means

```
mSocket = new SocketIO ( BASE_SOCKETIO_URL );
```

but there is serious problem in ANDROID
after run this, the garbage collector runs fast, and battery on device runs fast too.

i think SocketIO class instance has a large amount of memory 
so this cause garbage collecting.

is there any solutions?

or is there any methods to fire reconnect() after onDisconnect() fired?

please help.

thank you for reading.